# Tabs on the right

Tags: discussion, design

Hi All,

I've been using the new design. I like it. However I sometimes can't find the tab on the right, the one that says Newest/Featured/Hot/Votes/Active, I think it is because it is a little bit too small. Just my impression after using the app for a few hours.

Perhaps to phrase it as a question: what do you think?

Carlos

Comment: @carlsosdc I think this is an issue with getting used to the new design. Certain elements are different from the Beta "Sketchy" design. I say give it a few more days, since the design just went up yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the "problem" is that the system message stretching across the screen is being used for routine messages. The "system message" was designed to be used only under extraordinary circumstances… and it's supposed to *really* stand out. That drowns out the tab block just underneath it.

**Re-designing the top-right tabs to *out-scream* the screaming system message isn't really a good answer.**

Moderators are free to set the system message and many are using it to publicize routine aspects of the site. But when you *blast out* a message on every single screen across the entire site, that's just too much. We simply need a better way to provide system-wide announcements/messages so they don't *have* to use the Stack Exchange-equivalent of the [Emergency Broadcast System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_broadcast_system).

Comment: I agree; it was useful during meta but now it is a high time we should find better way of making announcements; for instance chat works very well for that.

Comment: @mbq I agree we should find a better way of making announcements; in particular I think we need a way to highlight current activity on meta on the parent site. I disagree that chat works very well for that. Chat is the *last* thing I look at, and surely it's intended for ongoing discussion, not announcements.

Comment: I think that using the right sidebar could help for this, but we'd need some way to collapse what's there - I pay no attention to the recent tags and badges, and I only rarely need to tweak my interesting/ignored tags.  That's a huge swath of screen that's going unused for me.